# Calling a Fortran .pyd file from Python and have 0.0 return

Tags: python, fortran77

I have a very basic question. I have some old FORTRAN77 code, and I complied it by f2py in Windows. When I called it in Python, the return value is 0.0 rather than the correct one.

Here is my **correct** FORTRAN CODE (for test) before compiling

```
  FUNCTION ttt (APPRAT, METRAT)

  REAL APPRAT, METRAT      

  IF(APPRAT.LE.0.0)THEN
    ttt = METRAT * 0.89218
  ELSE
    ttt = APPRAT
  ENDIF
  RETURN
  END
```

Here is the python code

```
import al4 #the name of compiled FORTRAN 77 code which is a .pyd file
ff=(al4.ttt(-1,10))
print(ff)
```

If everything is correct, I should get 8.9218 as a return value, but I always get 0.0. So can anyone give me some suggestions? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: I don't know anything about Fortran or the Fortran<->Python interface, but can it be related to the fact that -1 and 10 are integers while you are doing floating-point arithmetic?

Comment: Or is it because you are assigning to `APPRAT` instead of `ttt`?

Comment: @EmilVikström Thanks for the comment. I tried to feed two float values to FORTRAN code, but I still get 0.0. But you are correct, FORTRAN did return ttt back rather than APPRAT. Thank you for your help!

Comment: I don't know if this is a problem, but with the above function, ttt is not given any explicit type -- therefore fortran will treat it as a real function (since it starts with t).  I would think f2py is smart enough to figure out the type ambiguity, but when dealing with fortran code, one can never be too careful ...

Comment: @mgilson, thanks for the comment. So what is the standard way of writing this function in FORTRAN (define a function and return a value)? 
Sorry for this basic question, since I am new to both Python and FORTRAN...

Comment: @tao.hong  Just add `REAL ttt`  right after `REAL APPRAT, METRAT`.  Alternatively, you could do `REAL FUNCTION ttt(...)`.  They mean the same thing in Fortran.  Another thing that is generally considered good style is after the function declaration (`Function foo(...)`), to add the line `implicit none`.  This forces all the variables and their types to be declared, otherwise the compiler will raise an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a little something that I hacked together looking at the f2py documentation:

```
 c This is file al4.f

      FUNCTION ttt (APPRAT, METRAT)
      IMPLICIT NONE
      REAL APPRAT, METRAT,ttt
 cf2py intent(in), APPRAT,METRAT
 cf2py intent(out) ttt      

      IF(APPRAT.LE.0.0)THEN
         ttt = METRAT * 0.89218
      ELSE
         ttt = APPRAT
      ENDIF
      RETURN
      END
```

I then "compiled" it with:  `f2py -c al4.f -m al4`
and then ran your python script above (in the same directory as al4.so -- although the extension ".so" may be different depending on your system) and it worked.  the `cf2py` are special comments (fortran comments have a `c` in the first column) which tell f2py what to do with the arguments.  In this case, you have 2 inputs and 1 output...

**EDIT**  I should practice what I say in comments...(added IMPLICIT NONE to the function)

Comment: Thank you! It would be easier if Fortran supports something like "RETURN ttt"

Comment: The problem isn't here isn't Fortran.  In fact, in a Fortran program, you'd call your function the way you expect `result=ttt(v1,v2)`.  The problem is with how f2py decides to create a wrapper for your function ... In this case, it seems that we needed to explicitly tell f2py what it should do with the arguments.